# Click element to traversing across containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now I have a bunch of triggers and targets. When you click a `span`, the next `div` should have a class toggled on it. *The unique case* here is that Trigger Three should actually target the `div` **outside** the `ul`

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger">Trigger 1</span>
         <div class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger">Trigger 2</span>
         <div class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger">Trigger 3</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 3</div>
```

Right now, my jQuery looks like this.

```
var trigger = ".trigger";
var recipient = ".target";

$(trigger).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  if ($(recipient).hasClass("open")){
    $(trigger).not(this).next(recipient).removeClass("open");
  }
  if($(trigger).hasClass("active")){
    $(trigger).not(this).removeClass("active");
  }
  $(this).next(recipient).toggleClass("open");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

My question is two fold here:

**a) How can I get the click event for Trigger 3 to traverse outside the containing `ul` and over to the next `div`**

**b) Is there a way to more intelligently bind the target and trigger using an `id` or something? I know that for `label` you can use `for` to target an `input` id. Is there an equivalent in jQuery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your design approach I would make the following modification to your HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger" data-target-id="target-1">Trigger 1</span>
         <div id="target-1" class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger" data-target-id="target-2">Trigger 2</span>
         <div id="target-2" class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
         <span class="trigger" data-target-id="target-3">Trigger 3</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="target-3" class="target">Target to reveal when I press Trigger 3</div>
```

which in turn would result in some easier coding within your event listener like so:

```
var trigger = ".trigger";
var recipient = ".target";

$(trigger).click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  recipient = '#' + $(this).attr('data-target-id');

  /* - Code that modifies classes down here - */

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var target = $(this).next(recipient);
if (target.length == 0) { // reached the end of this div
    target = $(this).closest('ul').next(recipient);
}
target.toggleClass("open");
```